# Real-analysis: convergence of sequence and convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

True or false (if true, prove it otherwise give an counterexample). 
"Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\alpha$ with $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2a_n^{n/2}$ is convergent."

I'm guessing this is false. And would use as a counterexample the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{2})^n$. This gives $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac{1}{2}$.

But $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2a_n^{n/2}$=? And this is where I get stuck. I hope someone can help me or give me a hint, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example doesn't work: it is convergent since it is positive and smaller than $\sum_{n\ge 1}n^2/(3/2)^{n/2}<\infty$..

Comment: but dooesn't the $n^2$ in the series make it diverge?

Comment: @user301032 Nope. Actually what is stated is true: the series is always convergent.

Comment: No, $\sqrt(3/2)^n$ has an exponential growth..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the Root Test to prove convergence. Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n^2)^{1/n}=1$.

Comment: So applying the root test: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2 a_n^\frac{n}{2})^\frac{1}{n}$ gives us  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2 )^\frac{1}{n}$ *  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n^\frac{n}{2})^\frac{1}{n}$ which then gives us: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{a_n}$ which is less then 1 so the sum must converge?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Note that Paolo Leonetti's answer is in a sense better, more basic, since in effect he proves the correctness of the Root Test for this particular case, instead of simply quoting the Root Test.

Comment: Which book did/do you use for real-analysis?

Comment: @user301032: Rudin. Probably no longer the best, but familiar!

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Denote by $n_0$ an integer such that $\frac{1}{a_n} \ge \frac{1}{\alpha}-\varepsilon$ whenever $n\ge n_0$. Notice that $\frac{1}{\alpha}>1$. We conclude that
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}n^2a_n^{n/2} \ll \sum_{n\ge n_0} \frac{n^2}{\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}-\varepsilon\right)^{n/2}} < \infty.
$$
Therefore it is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt.

Since $\lim_n a_n=\alpha \in ]0,1[$, there exists $\beta \in ]0,1[$ such that $\sqrt{\alpha}<\beta<1$. Then $n^2 a_n^{n/2} < \beta^n$ whenever $n\ge n_0$, where $n_0$ is a sufficiently large integer. We conclude that
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}n^2a_n^{n/2} \le \sum_{n=1}^{n_0}n^2a_n^{n/2}+\sum_{n>n_0}\beta^n,
$$
which is finite.

Comment: Where did you learn this? From what book? I want to be able to understand this :)